# Chunking a list to size N and adding to a Data Frame ends up with missing data

Tags: python, pandas, split, iteration, chunks

I'm chunking a list into smaller lists of size n and trying to add each new list to a DataFrame. When I list the lists, all of the data is there; when i try to put the lists in a DataFrame the first list of the set disappears.

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

def divide_chunks(a,n):
    for i in range(0, len(a),n):
        yield a[i:i+n]


x = divide_chunks(my_list, n)
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

## gives me

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

I would like to put this into a DataFrame.

Here is how I'm trying to that

```
x = divide_chunks(my_list, n)

for i in x:

    emptydf = pd.DataFrame(x)

emptydf
```

I would expect the output to be like above but instead I'm missing the list that has 1:5

```
{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}

{0} 6   7   8   9   10

{1} 11  12  13  14  15

{2} 16  17  18  19  20
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not doing what you think it does:

```
x = divide_chunks(my_list, 4)

print(x)
```

Will return an object like such:

```
    <generator object divide_chunks at 0x2aaae0622e60>
```

Now you can directly use:

```
pd.DataFrame(x)

    0   1   2   3
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8
2   9   10  11  12
3   13  14  15  16
4   17  18  19  20
```

Comment: Thank you! Don't know why I didn't try it like that in the first place

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `np.array_split`. Here I added an extra value to show how it behaves with an uneven division

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_list = [*range(1, 22)]

N = 5
pd.DataFrame(np.array_split(my_list, range(N, len(my_list), N)))
#    0     1     2     3     4
#0   1   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0
#1   6   7.0   8.0   9.0  10.0
#2  11  12.0  13.0  14.0  15.0
#3  16  17.0  18.0  19.0  20.0
#4  21   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```